# Renaming existing Custom Taxonomy slug and labels in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to rename a custom taxonomy from a purchased theme on WordPress. I have successfully renamed the slug from "Director" to "Instructor" with the below code in my functions.php file.

```
function overwrite_director_slug( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ){
    if( 'video-director' == $taxonomy ){
        remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
        $args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => 'instructor');
        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'overwrite_director_slug', 10, 3 );
```

How do I rename the label that is located in the admin menu? I want to once again change the name from "Director" to "Instructor". (see image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to rename everything that you want on an existing custom taxonomy.

You can visualize first, the taxonomy data that you want to rename, using [`get_taxonomy()` WordPress function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_taxonomy/). The following displays in frontend footer, all the data for your taxonomy *(only visible for admins)*:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_footer_script_test_output', 10);
function wp_footer_script_test_output() {
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return;

    echo '<pre>'. print_r( get_taxonomy('video-director'), true ) . '</pre>';
}
```

Now you can see all the data that you can rename. Once done, you can remove that code.

The following, based on your code, will rename the taxonomy label located in the admin menu *(and optionally some other labels that you can remove)*:

```php
function overwrite_director_slug( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args ){
    if( 'video-director' == $taxonomy ){
        remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
        $args['rewrite'] = array('slug' => 'instructor'); 

        $args['labels']->menu_name = 'Instructor'; // <=== HERE For the "MENU NAME"

        $args['labels']->singular_name = 'Instructor'; // (optional)
        $args['labels']->name = 'Instructor'; // (optional)

        $args['label'] = 'Instructor';  // General label (optional)

        register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', 'overwrite_director_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I've been trying for hours trying to understand this, and your explanation is so helpful. I didn't know you could view the taxonomy data in the footer like this - so awesome!

For the line "Set back the modified Object", do we have to set it back because the $args is being called in the register_taxonomy()? I'm a little fuzzy on this concept.

Comment: I have made an update as you can change standard Object properties directly…